# Can't restore backup - password unknown

Tags: backup, factory-reset, password, google-pixel

I have a Google 6 Pro. I set up a "pattern" password (which I'll never do again - numbers and words are meant for my memory) and forgot the pattern.

After multiple tries, I decided to do a Factory Reset given I had saved all my contacts/apps/photos to Google.

After the factory reset, I was prompted to "set up phone with backup" - which I went do **BUT THEN** it asked me for the pattern password in order to set up using the backup which was my whole reason for doing a Factory Reset.

Is there a way to restore the backup (given I know the google mail account it's attached to and the password for that) without knowing the pattern?

Comment: most likely you can get your pictures from PC https://photos.google.com and contacts most likely bonded to google account, you probably won't lose it even when set up as fresh device